# C++ Function Pointer assignment cannot convert types inside a class

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

I have a simple class that has a pointer to a function. The constructor points it to the function "morning()" and I get the error message when compiling:

```
error: cannot convert ‘Test::morning’ from type ‘void (Test::)()’ to type ‘Test::function {aka void (*)()}’
     Test() {assignPtr = morning;}
```

The code does compile when the "morning()" and the typedef are declared outside the function and I can't figure out how to make it work within the current class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Test {
  public:
    Test() {assignPtr = morning;}
    void say(std::string a) {name = a; assignPtr();};
  private:
    typedef void(*function)();
    void morning() {std::cout << "Good morning, " << name << std::endl;}
    void night() {};
    function assignPtr;
    std::string name;
};

int main() {
    Test a;
    a.say("Miguel");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer to member function is not a regular function pointer; the class is part of the type and you need to specify which object you want to call it with.

You need to use the correct type

```
typedef void(Test::*function)();
```

and then adjust the syntax both when creating the pointer and when calling it.

```
Test() {assignPtr = &Test::morning;} // Get pointer-to-member
void say(std::string a) {name = a; (this->*assignPtr)();};  // Use pointer-to-member
```

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers and pointers to member functions are NOT the same thing.  That's what you're compiler is telling you.  The types do not match.  Your target is defined as `void(*)()` and you're trying to hand it `void(Test::*)()`.  They don't even have the same calling semantics.  The latter has a blind `Test*const this` parameter.

Change the type of `function` or give it a regular function to call.

Hint: any time your compiler errors out with a complaint of not being able to convert this to that...your types don't match.